# Math-grounded technique to translate recursion into while() loop?

Tags: oop, math, recursion, functional-programming, proof-of-correctness

What I am looking for, is some **math theory** enlightening how one can translate **arbitrary finite recursion** to a some kind of `while(...)` loop traditional in OOP. Or, in other case, how one can **prove** that given recursion can not be translated to a `while(...)` statement.

Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the context in **Dynamic Programming** or **Tail Recursion**. In Dynamic Programming, you can prove this by induction, as in recursive algorithms we define the function on the value of `n` base on the previous value of the function.

Comment: Do you have somewhat introductory papers or researches? Or books you personally would recommend to start from?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov asking for links to resources and tutorials is off-topic, not to mention that as it stands this question is already too broad.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog can you show me exact place, where I asked for links?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov `"Do you have somewhat introductory papers or researches?"` Doesn't have to be links, just resources in general. We are not a search engine service.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, can you show me exact place where I asked the person who gave an answer to search something?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov I did not give an answer. I was merely pointing out that your first comment, `"Do you have somewhat introductory papers or researches? Or books you personally would recommend to start from?"`, is off-topic. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).